# change vue cli create path location on Windows

Tags: windows, vue.js, vue-cli-4

I am just getting started on Vue.js and I seem to have run into a weirdness I could use some help with. When I creates a new project with the CLI it creates the new project folder in the root of my `user` folder. This is just plain bad practice. I would not mind putting them into a `vue-projects` subfolder but would like it even better if I could put them in my `c:\inetpup\` folder.

I can't seem to do either. If I specify a path during create I get the following error  `Error: name can only contain URL-friendly characters`. I have tried a number of different formats `vue create "vueprojects\helloworld"`, `vue create "vueprojects/helloworld/"`, `vue create ".\vueprojects\helloworld"`, `vue create "c:\inetpub\vueprojects\helloworld"` among others. I even true the vue ui but it gives me a JS run time error.

The docs and my Google fu are failing me. Seems like such a simple thing so I am baffled.

Comment: What directory are you in when you run the command?

Comment: The first argument should be the app name, so it doesnt accept paths. Try to use two commands, like `cd c:\inetpub\vueprojects && vue create helloworld `

Answer (score 0):

Forehead slap. It will create the project in the current folder.

So you have to cd into the folder you want to create the project in and then do your `vue create`.

Never mentioned in the vue cli guide or the tutorial I am using so one of those many "we assume you already knew it" things that hang us up learning new things.

Comment: `vue create` internally does a `git clone`, so it clones wherever you are.